# IntelliJ icons change after indexing project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The icons in my IntelliJ IDEA project view change once indexing has completed. I'm using 2017.1.2 Ultimate. As far as I've seen, the icons should not change as the "class" icons are more informative.

These are the icons that display as soon as I've opened the app.

[image: icons before indexing is complete]

These are what the icons change to.

[image: icons after indexing]

Comment: Did you install some custom icons/ide theme plug-in? Does it help if you disable it?

Comment: @CrazyCoder nope, the only plugins I've installed are PlayFramework, Scala, Spring and .ignore - nothing to do with icons or the theme.

Comment: Please share [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) after IDE startup.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  Here's a clean log after invalidating caches and restarting the app. https://gist.github.com/wayneashleyberry/ec9e76dcead659882efe33b305248e46

Comment: You said there is no any plugins for third-party themes or icons installed, but the log shows `Material Theme UI (0.2.3.2)`. Does it help if you [disable it](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html)?

Comment: Facepalm. No idea how that theme got there @CrazyCoder but disabling it did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is specific to the third-party **Material Theme UI** plug-in. [Disabling the plug-in](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a theme installed - not sure how it got there.

Thanks to @CrazyCoder for finding the cause.